# Load .json file to variable javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have created a PHP programm which allows to load a random .json file on my computer. When I select the file I want to display, I get the data from the selected .json file. At the beginning, I used a default file which I replaced with a variable. Here is the PHP code :

```
<?php

$uploaddir = 'uploads/';

$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$file_test = explode('.', $_FILES['file']['name']);
$file_ext= strtolower(end($file_test));

$expensions = array(".json");

        if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
            $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a DBC or an XML file.";
        }

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "<div style='font-size: 150%;'>". "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n"."</div>";

} else {
    echo "<div style='font-size: 150%;'>". "Oops, It seems you haven't uploaded a file ! Please make sure you have selected a .json file\n "."</div> <br>";
    echo "<div style='font-size: 150%;'>". "Returning to Home...\n "."</div>";
    header("Refresh: 3,URL=upload_file.php");
    exit();
}

echo basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

?>

<?php 

header("Refresh: 2,URL=json_content_extended.php?filename=".$uploadfile);
exit();

?>
```

Another file contains the code where I declared the requested value :

```
$json_file = file_get_contents($_REQUEST["filename"]);

$jfo = json_decode($json_file, true);
```

This is what I did before the javascript example below. I recreated the same example as above in javascript where I loaded a default .json file

I've entered the filename manually, but I would like to change it so I can load the file I want.
Here is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("file.json", function(json) {
        var tr;
        for (var i = 0; i < json.messages.length; i++) {
            var details = json.messages[i];
            for (var j = 0; j <= details.signals.length; j++) {
                tr = $('<tr/>');
                tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].start_bit + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].comment + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].bit_length + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].factor + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].offset + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].is_big_endian + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].is_signed + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].name + "</td>");
                $('#table_1').append(tr);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The example above is a part of my javascript file.
This is the output I get :

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RelHB.png)

The picture shows you the content of file.json. I wonder if there is somehow a possibility to set a variable instead of the file name. I would like to do the same thing I did in the PHP example, but this time in javascript.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? Have you tried putting a variable there?

Comment: Yes I did, and it don't work

Comment: So show us a [mcve] so we can tell why it didn't work.

Comment: In special, do tell us what error you get. Are you certain that the JSON file you are trying to load is available from your HTTP server?

Comment: @Quentin I modify my post

Comment: So your question isn't about using variables, but is actually about "in response to something you haven't explained" making a new Ajax request and then replacing the content of the table? Where's the code you wrote to attempt that which didn't work? You need a [mcve]. When do you want to do it? After a minute? When something is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var filename = 'file.json';
    $.getJSON(filename, function(json) {
        var tr;
        for (var i = 0; i < json.messages.length; i++) {
            var details = json.messages[i];
            for (var j = 0; j <= details.signals.length; j++) {
                tr = $('<tr/>');
                tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].start_bit + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].comment + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].bit_length + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].factor + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].offset + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].is_big_endian + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].is_signed + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].name + "</td>");
                $('#table_1').append(tr);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

If you want the user to enter the file name :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var filename = prompt("The file name of the JSON file to load:")
    $.getJSON(filename, function(json) {
        var tr;
        for (var i = 0; i < json.messages.length; i++) {
            var details = json.messages[i];
            for (var j = 0; j <= details.signals.length; j++) {
                tr = $('<tr/>');
                tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].start_bit + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].comment + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].bit_length + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].factor + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].offset + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].is_big_endian + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].is_signed + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].name + "</td>");
                $('#table_1').append(tr);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Good answer, though getting file name from user before starting $.getJSON() function would be a better approach here. +1 for answer.

Comment: Then the best thing would creating a modal. In that modal there is a form where the user enters the file name. When submitting the form, prevent default behavior of the form and call a function that do the computation above with the file name as a parameter

Comment: That would be great. Even if not that, in another answer given below, using JavaScript prompt() method would also work.

Comment: I edited my answer by adding code from @Bjartur Thorlacius answer

Comment: Don't forget to accept my answer if it is the one who solved your issue

Comment: I'm not the one who asked question @Ghassen Rjab, check question again for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138183/discussion-between-prime-coder-and-ghassen-rjab).

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You can change the first three lines to:

```
const filename = prompt("The file name of the JSON file to load:")
$(document).ready(function() {
$.getJSON("file.json", function(json) {
```

A better user interface would be to have a HTML form with a text input and binding your anonymous function to the clicking of an associated button instead of to `$(document).ready`. Note that then you do not said form to submit any request to your server. `$.getJSON` takes care of downloading the JSON file from your server.

Answer (score -1):

create a variable for fileName is javascript, load that variable with your preferred language, and then just use it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myFile = 'mydynamicfile.json';
    $.getJSON(myFile, function(json) {
        var tr;
        for (var i = 0; i < json.messages.length; i++) {
            var details = json.messages[i];
            for (var j = 0; j <= details.signals.length; j++) {
                tr = $('<tr/>');
                tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].start_bit + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].comment + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].bit_length + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].factor + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].offset + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].is_big_endian + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].is_signed + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + details.signals[j].name + "</td>");
                $('#table_1').append(tr);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var filename= 'file.json';

$.getJSON(filename, function(json) {});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.